# is there a way to move and display a character in a grid without displaying a new grid every time I move?

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

I am trying to make a game in C using a 3x3 grid using 2d array:

> | o | _ | _ |
>   | _ | _ | _ |
>   | _ | _ | _ |

Does anyone know how can I move 'o' from other positions (like from 0,0 to 0,1) without displaying another grid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not portable, but a very easy way if you are under some Unix terminal is using [escape sequences](http://www.termsys.demon.co.uk/vtansi.htm):

```
#define gotoxy(x,y) printf("\033[%d;%dH", (y), (x))

int main(void)
{
    gotoxy(4, 2);
    printf("o");
    return 0;
}
```

should print something like:

```
|_|_|_|
|_|o|_|
|_|_|_|
```

whithout redrawing the whole grid

Comment: can you suggest some other method to pull it off? (still discovering C lol, hoping to learn some more solutions)

Comment: Google for ncurses on linux, and I'm not sure on Windows but conio was used for that some decades ago